# Build up a cell array with different amount of zeros in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I want a cell array with 1 zero in the first column, 2 zeros in the next etc up to n.

For this Im trying to use arrayfun the following way:

```
index = 1:n;
a{index}=arrayfun(@(index) zeros(index,1),1);
```

I get the error:

```
The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy
the left hand side.
```

What am I doing wrong? Also tried deal. I want to do it without for loops.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid loops? Arrayfun *is* a loop.

Comment: Btw you're looking for: `index = 1:10;
a =arrayfun(@(x) zeros(x,1),index,'UniformOutput',false);`

Comment: but yeah, sometime it's easier and clearer to use a for loop

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) -

```
mat2cell(zeros(n*(n+1)/2,1),1:n)
```

Sample run -

```
>> n = 4;
>> out = mat2cell(zeros(n*(n+1)/2,1),1:n);
>> celldisp(out)
out{1} =
     0
out{2} =
     0
     0
out{3} =
     0
     0
     0
out{4} =
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

Comment: That's very clever!